# How to automate archiving a copy of mails received/sent through sendmail MTA on CentOS?

Tags: email, unix, sendmail, archive, mbox

We have an application which sends out emails and also receives emails from the users which trigger functionality in the application. There are a lot of emails going back and forth. We would like to have an ability to automate archival of all emails sent / received and if possible have a searchable archival. We are talking about almost 1 GB of emails a day.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Archiving milters](https://www.milter.org/milters/archiving/mostrecent/1).